Run Python file in SSIS package by SQL agent job
I wrote a Python script to create partitions. When I use SSIS package to run the Python file, it was successful -> created the partition. But when I use SQL Agentjob to set up a schedule using SSIS catalog, when check log of SSIS catalog it shows and the partiton cannot be created.

The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0" Error

Can anyone help me to solve that? Thank you in advance.
Note: I am using SQL2019.
I try to hardcode was 0 but it is not successfully.

please add what you wrote in python script. Also add what is expected output, what you are getting. And then clarify where you need help. Including code/errors/example improve question quality.

Did you try logging the output of sql agent step somewhere and check it?
